# Подключение репозитория Git к idea

Tags: git

При попытке клонировать репозиторий из Git  в idea появляется ошибка:

> the directory already exists and it is not empty.

Насколько я понял, нужно очистить репозиторий от всех файлов, а там уже есть .idea. Нашел решение в виде команд:

```
git init .
git remote add -f origin <repository-url>
git checkout <branch-name>
```

Предполагается, что Git должен взлететь после этого, но нет, что-то не так. Кто сталкивался с этой проблемой?

Comment: Если нужно клонировать репозиторий, и существующая директория не нужна, просто удалите ее и делайте `git clone`. Создавать новый пустой репозиторий через `git init` прочее перед этом не нужно.

Comment: В найденном вами решении между `git remote …` и `git checkout …` пропущено `git pull`

Answer (score 0):

Похоже вам может помочь `$rm -rf ..?* .[!.]* *`
Удалит все файлы в том числе файлы с точкой, после чего вы можете склонировать репозиторий в эту директорию.

Так же после выполнения команды вы можете клонировать следующим образом.
`git clone https://github.com/myrepo/myrepo-com.git .` - точкой в конце которая укажет, что клонировать нужно в текущую директорию